# Clicking page elements and using them as form data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I am making a site that has a photos page. On the photos page I would like to have albums and also single photos. I would also like users to have the ability to create a new album, by just clicking my "+create album" button, and then simply clicking images that they would like to have stored in that album. I am unsure of what I need to know how to do. I know how to create a form, which is basically what I need, and use php to store the data in my database to create the album, but what I don't know how to do is have values entered into my form by users from just simply clicking the images they want in the album. Here is an illustration, with steps.

[image: Album Creation Process]

Comment: you need to work with Javascript and AJAX requests..

Comment: are you using a single page to do all these?

Comment: I could do it with two, i think It would minimize the javascript

Answer (score 7):

Basicly to answer your question on "how to get a user defined value from an image into a form" you can use this:

#### DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/DdNZz/

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // add event handler to the image
    $('#image').click( function(event) {

        // put value into the input field
        $('#input').val( $(this).data('myvalue') );
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-200-200-4.jpg" data-myvalue="image one clicked" alt="">
<input type="text" id="input" value="">
```

Using the `data-*`-attribute lets you specify your own values and is perfectly valid HTML5 whereas older browser can handle that too without problems.

But there is a lot more to think about regarding your idea and I'm not sure, whether this would be to much for a Q&A on SO.

Comment: the question is too broad for SO Q&A.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? What's wrong with this answer?

Comment: Even if the question is too broad, does that mean the answer should be downvoted? I didn't think so...

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="click-the-picture" src="photo1.jpg">
<img class="click-the-picture" src="photo2.jpg">
<img class="click-the-picture" src="photo3.jpg">

<form id="theform">
<button>Save</button>
</form>

<script>
$(function(){
   $('.click-the-picture').live('click',function(){
       $('#theform').append('<input type="hidden" name="photo[]" value="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"');
   });
});
</script>
```

you can try this code to generate the hidden inputs for every picture click and then send them to database